# codeigniter CMS form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, content-management-system

Firstly Im new to CodeIgniter and MVC.

I am Creating a CMS and coudln't decide which route to take with do I have two applications (front end/CMS) or just create the admin as a controller. I opted for one application and creating the admin via a Controller.

Doing it this way I have ran into a problem with form validation where if it doesn't validate I cant load the form I have to redirect which then means it wont repopulate the unvalidated fields. I use a variable in the 3rd URI segment to determine whether to display a form for inserting a new record, a populated form for editing a record, or a tabled list of all records.

**The form posts to /admin/videos/save**

```
function videos()
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {

        $this->load->model('videos_model');

        $data['section'] = "Videos";
        $data['area']    = "Videos";
        $data['mode']    = $this->uri->segment(3, 'create');
        $data['user_id']  = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username'] = $this->tank_auth->get_username();

        if ($data['mode'] == 'edit') {

            $data['ID']     = $this->uri->segment(4);
            $data['videos'] = $this->videos_model->get_videos($data['ID']);

        } elseif ($data['mode'] == 'list') {

            if ($this->uri->segment(4)) {
                $data['filter'] = $this->uri->segment(4);

                $data['videos'] = $this->videos_model->get_filtered_videos($data['filter']);
            } else {
                $data['videos'] = $this->videos_model->get_filtered_videos();
            }
        } elseif ($data['mode'] == 'save') {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('videoTitle', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('Code', 'Youtube Code', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                redirect('/admin/videos');
            } else {
                $this->videos_model->set_videos();
                redirect('/admin/videos/list');
            }
        }

        if ($data['mode'] != "create" && empty($data['videos'])) {
            show_404();
        }



        $this->load->view('admin/templates/head', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/body_navbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/videos', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Am I setting about this the wrong way, Should I use two application folders or have 3 controllers for editing/inserting/viewing all. Or is there a solution to my current setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have continued to use my one application folder and the entire admin as a controller.

I have solved my form validation and repopulating issue by continuing to redirect back to the form but storing the form fields and errors in a session.

I destroy the error data in the session once viewed but leave the other info intact which allows the user to navigate away and come back and the info will remain. Once the form is validated correctly and information stored in the database it destroys the session data.

```
    function videos()
{
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {

        $this->load->model('videos_model');

        $data['section'] = "Videos";
        $data['area']    = "Videos";
        $data['mode']    = $this->uri->segment(3, 'create');
        $data['user_id']  = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username'] = $this->tank_auth->get_username();

        if ($this->session->userdata('videoTitle'))
            $data['videoTitle'] = $this->session->userdata('videoTitle');
        if ($this->session->userdata('Code'))
            $data['Code'] = $this->session->userdata('Code');
        if ($this->session->userdata('videoTitle'))
            $data['description'] = $this->session->userdata('description');
        if ($this->session->userdata('errors')){
            $data['errors'] = $this->session->userdata('errors');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('errors');
        }

        if ($data['mode'] == 'edit') {

            $data['ID']     = $this->uri->segment(4);
            $video_data = $this->videos_model->get_videos($data['ID']);
            $data['videoTitle'] = $video_data['videoTitle'];
            $data['Code'] = $video_data['blipCode'];
            $data['description'] = $video_data['description'];

        } elseif ($data['mode'] == 'list') {

            if ($this->uri->segment(4)) {
                $data['filter'] = $this->uri->segment(4);

                $data['videos'] = $this->videos_model->get_filtered_videos($data['filter']);
            } else {
                $data['videos'] = $this->videos_model->get_filtered_videos();
            }
        } elseif ($data['mode'] == 'save') {
            $this->load->helper('form');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('videoTitle', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('Code', 'Youtube Code', 'required');


            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                $formdata = array(
                    'videoTitle' => $this->input->post('videoTitle'),
                    'Code' => $this->input->post('Code'),
                    'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                    'errors' =>  validation_errors()
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($formdata);
                redirect('/admin/videos');
            } else {
                $this->videos_model->set_videos();
                $this->session->unset_userdata('videoTitle');
                $this->session->unset_userdata('Code');
                $this->session->unset_userdata('description');
                redirect('/admin/videos/list');
            }
        }

        $this->load->view('admin/templates/head', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/body_navbar', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/videos', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't  used CodeIgniter's form helper nor validation lib, so excuse my ignorance, but is there any particular reason you're not doing this as AJAX post instead?

> Am I setting about this the wrong way, Should I use two application
>   folders or have 3 controllers for editing/inserting/viewing all. Or is
>   there a solution to my current setup?

Why 3 controllers? You can have a single controller with multiple functions. Honestly, I'd recommend just doing a simple AJAX post on your form and returning some JSON data whether validation passed or not -- no need for redirects.

Something like:

// AJAX

```
function validateForm() {
  $.post('route/to/controller', {"apple": appleValue, "peach": peachValue}, function(data) {

     json = $.parseJSON(data);

        if (json.success)
           alert('Great!');
        else
            alert('Nope!');
});
```

//Controller

```
function validateForm()
{
  $data['success'] = ...validation checks...

  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Once the form is processed it will take them to the list view of all records with the one they just inserted at the top. As this involved a page load and codeigniter had form validation I didn't see the need to complicate it with Ajax. Thank you for the suggestion. You say there is no need for the three controllers so is how I have set out the controllers how you would of done it?

Comment: Point taken. You may have 3 controllers if you so wish, but I just wanted to point out that it's not required. I would have created a single controller named admin and created 3 (or as many as you need) functions within it, videoView(), videoEdit() and videoSave(). I base my controllers on a per-section model, for example; dashboard, admin, posts, account, etc. but you may do as you please.